# How to map keyboard keys to joystick buttons using joy2key?

Tags: wine, gamepad, joystick

There isn't much documentation on the game I'm playing using WINE, and it doesn't detect a joystick. I want to use `joy2key` to map keyboard keys to joystick buttons, but can't figure out exactly how to use its command line interface.

```
joy2key -dev /dev/input/js0 -terminal
```

That command shows what to press, but I can't figure out how to map the keys since the instructions are not clear.

Comment: Here is my explanation how to fix: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1438422/22-04-the-xbox-controller-of-wine-has-a-mistake-how-to-fix/1438603#1438603

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `antimicro`, it is a fork of `joy2key` and has a `GUI`, use this `PPA` for 12.04 to 15.10

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ryochan7/antimicro
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install antimicro
```

For 16.04 to 17.10 use this `PPA`

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mdeguzis/libregeek
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install antimicro
```

[Source](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/09/gamepad-keyboardmouse-mapping-app.html)

[image: Screnshot of AntiMicro and key mapping]

Comment: Thanks a ton do you know ho much time i have spent fixing compilation of rejoystick and figuring out how joy2ky works ? around 2 hours now

Comment: I too have been through this hell, I assure you, this is a great application :)

Comment: they changed the package name its antimicro now insted of anti-micro

Comment: PPA has moved to ppa:mdeguzis/libregeek, I updated the post

Comment: My system says antimicro is not found either at that PPA or the one on the github page.

Comment: @levitopher Updated for 16.04+ versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: There is not version for 18.04. You can follow instructions to compile in [antimicro repository](https://github.com/AntiMicro/antimicro).

Comment: AntimicroX is now available on Flathub.  Probably the easiest way to get the latest version.

Answer (score 9):

For those looking for a solution that's easily installable on Ubuntu 18.04+, I found `qjoypad` in the official Ubuntu repositories. Install it like this:

```bsh
sudo apt install qjoypad
```

Then, it should be available in your launcher. It starts as a system tray icon, and you can launch the configurator by right clicking on it.

Personally, I really like the quick bind option that lets you press a key on a gamepad and then a key on your keyboard to update the mapping for that layout automatically. Note that it does indeed natively support multiple gamepads.

For me, I had some trouble with getting the right click to launch the configurator to work on the Unity 7.5 desktop - and the left-click menu doesn't appear to have an option for launching it. Thankfully, there's a workaround for this too. Simply launch `qjoypad` like so:

```bsh
qjoypad --notray
```

....this will disable the system tray icon and instead launch a window with the icon in it instead - which works as expected.

This can be made to happen automatically by editing `/usr/share/applications/qjoypad.desktop`. Find the line that starts with `Exec=`, and append `--notray` to  the end of it (make sure that there's a space after `qjoypad` at  the end of the line and `--notray`).

Comment: This solution works in Debian too.